# installing opencv for python 2.7 on a MAC

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv

I installed opencv via the command `pip install opencv-python` and then when I import cv2 in python I get the error `ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime`

I would like to install opencv for python 2.7 on a mac. How can I resolve this error ? I am using El Capitan.

I installed opencv prior to this using `brew install opencv` but then I uninstalled it using `brew uninstall opencv` before using pip.

Comment: Are you using the default install of python on MacOS? I've found this site particularly helpful when installing OpenCV on both my Mac (Sierra) and Ubuntu machines: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works !

```
sudo pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10
```

El Capitan has an issue detailed here http://answers.opencv.org/question/182067/import-cv2-throws-symbol-not-found-_clock_gettime/

In order to circumvent this issue, I rolled back to an earlier version of opencCV.

A trick to check the available version with pip do

```
sudo pip install opencv-python==
```

This will return all the available version and then you can try the ones that work for you.

Dont forget to `pip uninstall` when moving to a different version

Comment: Confirmed 3.3.0.10 is the newest version that works on El Capitan (3.3.1.11, [the next release](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#history) does not work). Also confirmed it works correctly using Python 3.6 install with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is an issue with python-opencv and the mac operating system *That you are using*. From the link below it looks like Apple changed something to do with _clock_gettime function, meaning the maintainers of python-opencv will need to update.

The commenters on the post below managed to fix the issue by upgrading to Sierra

http://answers.opencv.org/question/182067/import-cv2-throws-symbol-not-found-_clock_gettime/

Comment: thanks. I just saw that. I dont have enough space to upgrade to High Sierra. I will try to use an earlier version of opencv to see if any of them work